# What are the differences between CClientDC and CWnd::GetDC

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to know if there are any differences between CClientDC and CWnd::GetDC. It seems that both beave fairly equal, despite the fact of resource allocation and semantic.

An Example:

```
CClientDC dc(this); // "this" is sub-classed object of CWnd
CGdiObject* oldObj = dc.SelectStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
... do some with dc ...
dc.SelectObject(oldObj);
// Device object is stack object, ReleaseDC called automaticly
```

or

```
CDC* dc = this->GetDC(); // "this" is sub-classed object of CWnd
CGdiObject* oldObj = dc->SelectStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
... do some with dc ...
dc->SelectObject(oldObj);
// Device context belongs to a window class no need to call ReleaseDC 
// I don't allocate dc, so I don't delete it
```

Both code snippets seems identical, beside different semantics, but where is difference, if any? And what do I have to concern on their usage.

Is GetDC() just a short cut for CClientDC(this)? 
I'm a little confused.

**Edit**: The device context returned by CClientDC() beaves different - under certain circumstances - from the device context returned by GetDC() and I would like to know why.

Example:

```
HRC hRC = wglCreateContext(GetDC()->m_hDC); // work's as expected.
```

but

```
ClientDC dc(this)   
HRC hRC = wglCreateContext(dc.m_hDC); // does not work as expected, output in
                                      // clients device context not screen visible.
```

So there must be subtile differences between both client device contexts on the same window, but MSDN does not give me information on that. See function description on MSDN for [CClientDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dc7zsf0y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/71eseab0%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: A little time reading the docs on [`CWnd::GetDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0(v=vs.80).aspx) and [`CClientDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc7zsf0y(v=vs.80).aspx) would likely answer your question. They're both client device context wrappers.

Answer (score 4):

There 3 types of DC: Common DC, class DC and private DC. If GetDC() returns a common DC, you must call ReleaseDC() on it. If GetDC() returns a class DC or private DC, nothing will happen if you call ReleaseDC().

So it's very possible there is a resource leak in your second piece of code.

This article describes the 3 types of DC in detail: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2078/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-Intermediates

Answer (score 1):

ClientDC() manages getDC() and releaseDC() implicitly.we dont need to take care of it.

And on calling GetDC(),If we are using non window device context then we need to explicitly call releasedc().

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to realize about CClientDC is that it is a *class* - and so when it goes out of context, so does your dc.  The class constructor calls GetDC, the destructor calls ReleaseDC.  That means that the dc is gone at the next closing brace.